# QuartzScheduler - SimpleTrigger executing repeatedly

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm running Quartz version 1.8.4

When using the following code

```
    simpleTrigger.setName(triggerName);
    simpleTrigger.setGroup(triggerGroupName);
    simpleTrigger.setStartTime(startTime);
    simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(0);
    simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(0L);
    simpleTrigger.setEndTime(null);
```

I get a trigger that executes multiple times. On checking the database, I found:

```
TRIGGER_NAME TRIGGER_GROUP REEAT_COUNT REPEAT_INTERVAL TIMES_TRIGGERED
simplejob    simplegroup   0           0               3
```

And the trigger keeps being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extract from the [Quartz Scheduler tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05)

> The repeat count can be zero, a positive integer, or the constant value SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY. The repeat interval property must be zero, or a positive long value, and represents a number of milliseconds. Note that a repeat interval of zero will cause 'repeat count' firings of the trigger to happen concurrently (or as close to concurrently as the scheduler can manage).

`SimpleTrigger` instances are built using `TriggerBuilder` (for the trigger's main properties) and is be a better way to create the trigger.

Using the `TriggerBuilder` to build a trigger for a specific moment in time (your start date) with no repeats:

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() 
.withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
.startAt(myStartTime) // some Date 
.forJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings
.build();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am so sorry that I paste the wrong version number.